# IPAddress null for MVC 6 ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do you extract the IPAddress in ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 vNext ?
I'm using RC1.

This doesn't work and returns null on non localhost addresses.

```
if (httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
{
     currentIp = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
}
```

This works, but it's messy :

```
    private static string GetIPAddress(HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
        string keys = string.Empty;
        foreach (string key in httpRequest.Headers.Keys)
        {
            keys = keys + key + "#";
        }

        string[] arrKeys = keys.Split('#');

        int x = 0;
        foreach (string value in httpRequest.Headers.Values)
        {
            if (arrKeys[x].Trim() == "X-Forwarded-For")
            {
                string[] arrIP = value.Split(':');
                if (arrIP[0] != null)
                {
                    // ip found
                    return arrIP[0];
                }
            }
            x++;
        }

        // no ip found
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not currently work as expected because of a bug that prevents the correct headers from being parsed correctly. You can track this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/17) from their repo.

Until they close that issue, you'll have to use the workaround.